# Cannot find module 'aproba'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have `nodejs version 10.15.0` and `Angular CLI version 1.7.3` and `Angular version 5.2.9` but when I am trying install any `npm packages` or trying to update the `npm`,

it is showing throwing the below error: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ZN5.png)

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "so-portal-rwd",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.5",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "adal-angular5": "^1.0.36",
    "angular-user-idle": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-draggable": "^1.4.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "marked": "^0.4.0",
    "mat-video": "^2.5.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^4.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.5.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/marked": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install aproba`?  Can you edit your `package.json` into your question?

Comment: Yes I have tried to install aproba but I am getting the same error.

Comment: looks like you need to install the dependency... @zero298 looks to have suggested this - I'd try it

Comment: @ayushsharma I've rolled back your edit, not sure what your intent is, but you're making it more difficult for us to help you...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sh
npm install --save aproba
```

If it still didn't work try cleaning cache and installing again:

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install --save aproba
```

Comment: Why `npm cache clean --force` ? There's a warning about doing that for a reason.

Comment: I have tried both 'npm cache clean --force' and 'npm install --save aproba' but still I am getting the same error. I think there is some problem with npm.